# ASP.NET MVC web application not running with HTTPS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5.2

After all these months, suddenly, my ASP.NET MVC application runs on HTTP instead of HTTPS in the debugger.

When I run it by clicking pressing F5 in Visual Studio or by clicking Debug -> Start Debugging, it runs with an **http://** scheme and not **https**, like it had been running for all the months up until now.

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 RTM.

Long ago, when I created this project, I had changed its project properties and set **SSL Enabled** to **True** and also set the **SSL URL** as follows:

[image]

I am not sure what changed in that or in the **Project Properties** dialog, which now looks as follows.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the **Web** tab > **Project Url**, try to specify your HTTPS address instead of HTTP. That may do the trick.